# Probability of seeing i but not j in k multinomial trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we have a multinomial distribution $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ and we perform $k$ trials. What is the probability that we see (at least) an outcome $i$ but none of the outcomes is $j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the probability that none of the outcomes is $j$ minus the probability that none of the outcomes is either $i$ or $j$:

$$
\left(1-p_j\right)^k-\left(1-p_i-p_j\right)^k\;.
$$

Comment: from 
$$A \setminus B=B^c \setminus (A \cup B)^c$$